json_query multiple selection selecting empty value
I have below json and i am trying to use json_query in ansible to select 'name' and 'id' of tasks only with failed state.
I am using
{"a": {
  "b": {
    "c": [
      {"json": {"name": "test1", "tasks": [{"id": 0, "state": "failed" },{"id": 1, "state": "failed" },{"id": 2, "state": "running" }]}},
      {"json": {"name": "test2", "tasks": [{"id": 0, "state": "running" }]}},
      {"json": {"name": "test3", "tasks": [{"id": 0, "state": "failed" }]}}
    ]
  }
}}

I am using below query, however this is also selecting name(test2) which has state as running.
a.b.c[].json[].{name: name, status: tasks[?state=='failed'].id}

Output
[
  {
    "name": "test1",
    "status": [
      0,
      1
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "test2",
    "status": []
  },
  {
    "name": "test3",
    "status": [
      0
    ]
  }
]

I would like to get only test1 and test3 with ids like below. Can anyone help me understand why my query is not working as expected?
[
  {
    "name": "test1",
    "status": [
      0,
      1
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "test3",
    "status": [
      0
    ]
  }
]

